# Why do microsoft word's pictures not appearing?

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office, apple-silicon

I recently purchased that M1 Macbook pro that I'm using for around 3 months now and I noticed that now when microsoft office Word is opened it doesn’t show any of the pictures I have included in the file, only the text content.
I checked if it was a version issue by redoaloading the App and reainstalling from my school's website, but it is still showing the same issue.

[image]

- Is anyone having the same problem?
- How do I go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Outline or Draft View? Those views will not show images.